# How To Quickly Loop WAV Files Without Delay In Python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wav

I'm trying to loop a WAV file so it seamlessly plays in Python, but I didn't have any luck with:

```
os.system('aplay /home/pi/Desktop/F1/sample.wav')
```

There is a small delay between playback of this tiny (under 1000kb) WAV file when using a while loop. Is there another library that I could import to do this faster and natively in Python? Could my problem be solved with buffering, and if so, how do I accomplish this with said library? This is on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+, by the way.

Comment: There's overhead in calling `system` each time, you should create an `aplay` subprocess using `subprocess.Popen`, and then write the `.wav` data to its stdin in a loop.